# Running KDE as root

Tags: linux, kde

KDE panels look strange with black colors when I login using root account.

Is it possible to make KDE look normal?

I am using root account because I spend most of the time performing administration tasks and I don't want to type my strong password so frequently.

Comment: Learn `sudo` and `kdesu`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

log in with the normal / user account.

and use `sudo su -` to be root in the terminal.
in case the administrative tools you use are GUI based start them from the root terminal

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is actually my workaround for this issue. What I really need is to know how to configure KDE to look the way I want exactly.